# C# 9.0 records ToString()

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

If I look in the [spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/records) it says

> The record includes a synthesized method equivalent to a method declared as follows: public override string ToString();

however using [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQGMD2A3KCCWUAdjKkvAkcgD4ACATAIwCwAUG0VALYoAOU6CAAJajAHQAlOCXw8xAYUxde+ADYQEAZQ3Z8g5GwDebIaZEBmEfSEBJZAFEAHjA2dVNovhiGAvmz/srEhYCAAmQhIQ6AAUogAMQpqMADQijAma9ACUANxs+axAA) and as I see in my VS16.8.0 Preview 2.1 code:

```
record Rec(string S1, string S2);
```

`ToString` is not auto-generated.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe a bug in Sharplab? Did you try to check their issue tracker?

Comment: Preview == "not yet done".  Switch to "master (15 Sep 2020)" to see it done.

Comment: Which branch did you use? The current .NET 5 version is RC1. Even before that though, `ToString()` was generated if you used `master`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the blog post from Microsoft [Announcing .NET 5.0 RC 1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0-rc-1/#c-9-records) you need at least .NET 5.0 RC 1 for `record.ToString()` to work.

> Records are perhaps the most important new feature in C# 9. They offer a broad feature set (for a language type kind), some of which requires RC1 or later (like record.ToString()).

To use .NET RC 1, you need to update your Visual Studio:

> You need the latest preview version of Visual Studio (including Visual Studio for Mac) to use .NET 5.0.

Which probably means you need [Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8 Preview 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-preview#16.8.0-pre-3.0) which was released September 14, 2020.

---

**Edit:** Like Hans Passant mentioned in the comments, using the master branch should fix the issue in SharpLab. Here's a [working example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxAgrgOwD4AEBMAjALABQZAKnLAAQw0C8NmcA7gBQBsAlANxllchAJzsYAOgoB7AMowEAS0wBzdtz4DSmCGGoAHCAGM4NIeIBKWGAt3iAwlLB6FAG0QzEANwXGoZAN5kNMGmAMym+DQAklAAogAe8AjaLlGYCjD+AL5kOeSkuOEIcIZSCAAmNFSw7Er0AGJSUhr5QA=). If you use the branch *C# 9: Records (7 Jun 2020)*, the properties of the record are not included in the resulting string.